# Array_udiff array of objects so that array contains object with only 1 instance of a particular method exists

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to transorm an array of objects so that for instance, the array will only contain 1 object where the object property 'bar' = b.

So I'd like to turn:

```
   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] = 1
    [foo] => 'a' 
    [bar] => 'b' )

    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 2
    [foo] => 'a' 
    [bar] => 'c' )

    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 3
    [foo] => 'y' 
    [bar] => 'b' )  )
```

into:

```
     Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] = 1
    [foo] => 'a' 
    [bar] => 'b' )

    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 2
    [foo] => 'a' 
    [bar] => 'c' )
```

However, I need this to work on a larger scale, so I am stumped on how to combine array_filter, array_udiff and array_slice to get what I want.  I was thinking that array_filter would get me all the keys where `'foo' = 'b'`.  Then I could take this array and array_udiff it against the original to get the items where `'foo'=! 'b'`.  Then I could slice the matches from the array_filter to get a single-key array... and merge that back with the array_udiff difference.

```
$matches = array_filter($array, "bar_filter");

$remainder = array_udiff($array, $matches, 'compare_objects');

$single =  array_slice( $matches, 0, 1);

$result = array_merge($single, $remainder);

function foobar_filter($obj) {
    if ( $obj->bar == 'b' ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function compare_objects($obj_a, $obj_b) {
  return $obj_a->id = $obj_b->id;
}
```

My compare_objects function is off for sure, but I don't know what to put there.  Would it be better to just run a second array_filter to get the non-matching items?  I need to split the array into keys where `'bar'='b'` and where `'bar'!='b'` and merge it back together with only 1 object where `'bar'='b'`

Comment: So you will have two arrays, one filled with objects having the property `bar == b`, and the other filled with objects having property `bar != b`, and then you want to merge these two arrays together into one array and it will contain only 1 object with a property `bar == b` .. right?

Comment: when you put it like that... ;/  but yes, that is what i mean.

Comment: I'm just trying to rephrase your question, I'm not being ironic ;) .. in second code peace where it says **into**, I see also an object where `[bar] = c`, so I guess that is not the final result? And is there something specific about this one object how it can be chosen out of all the rest with `bar == b`?

Comment: No worries. As I was writing it I was worried that it wouldn't make any sense.  I had a hard time searching for related questions because I couldn't phrase it very well.  `[bar] = c` is a permissible result. I only want to limit `[bar] = b` to one instance, but all other permutations of `[bar]` are ok.  There isn't anything special about the choice of `[bar]==b`, the first instance will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for clarity, I'll do it in one loop.

```
$matches = array();
$remainder = array();

// $index if you need to maintain index=>object relation
foreach($array as $index => $object) {
  if($object->bar == "b")
    $matches[] = $object;
  else
    $remainder[] = $object;
}
```

--  for loop

```
for($index=0,$count=count($array);$index<$count;$index++) {
  if($object->bar == "b")
    $matches[] = $array[$index];
  else
    $remainder[] = $array[$index];
}
```

--

then you would like to merge the result with the first index in `$matches`

```
$result = array_merge(array($matches[0]),$remainder);
```

If this is the case, then you just need to change the compare object body, which should do the trick in filtering the remaining objects out

```
return $obj_a->id == $obj_b->id ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Is the foreach loop faster than array_filter?  Or is that strictly for clarity?  It seems like you would then no longer need the compare_object function.  Also, you have a few typos in the variable names... I tried to correct them but it wasn't enough characters to let me edit.

Comment: That is something you have to measure, although `array_filter` and `array_udiff` are practically native functions which might turn out to be faster, both have to iterate the largest array, in total twice.

Comment: and if there aren't enough characters to edit, add something at the end of the post "edit some typos, untill you reach the ammount of characters" always does the trick :P

Comment: Cool.  The foreach loop plus the array_merge does what I am looking for!  I don't think the array_udiff is necessary any longer.  Thank you!

Comment: @helgatheviking just wanted to comment that if this works, I'm going to bed cause I can't write one single valid code anymore, good luck wit it ;)

Comment: go to bed! thanks again.  it does work. I was struggling with understanding array_udiff when I didn't need to.  Cheers!